# Read the content of a div from a NET:HTTP response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http

I am doing a http request to a website and I would like to store the value of a div from the response.

This is what I am doing in the controller:

```
class RoomsController < ApplicationController
  require "uri"
  require "net/http"
  require 'json'
  require 'cgi'

  def test    
    dialect = params[:dialect]
    text = params[:text]

    uri = URI('http://www.degraeve.com/cgi-bin/babel.cgi')
    params = { :w => text, :d => dialect }
    uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)

    res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
    data = res if res.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)

    render json: data.body

  end

end
```

I am passing 2 parameters using GET method to get the response. But I need just the content of a div. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this:

```
dialect = current_user.dialect.name
    text = params[:text]

    uri = URI('http://www.degraeve.com/cgi-bin/babel.cgi')
    params = { :w => text, :d => dialect }
    uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)

    response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)

    render inline: response.body.html_safe, layout: false if response.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
```

and then got the div that I wanted in a .js file.